# OpenCV: not authorized to capture video - mac

Tags: python, macos, opencv, permissions, apple-m1

I'm trying use OpenCV through a 3rd party app called [3D Slicer](https://www.slicer.org), but I get the following error:

```
'OpenCV: not authorized to capture video (status 0), requesting...
OpenCV: camera failed to properly initialize!
```

I tried running Slicer as root with `sudo` but this didn't change anything

I added those two key-string pairs to Info.plist, but this also didn't change anything:

```xml
<key>com.apple.security.device.camera</key>
<string>used_to_track_your_hand</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>also_used_to_track_your_hand</string>
```

Is there a way to always gran OpenCV access to the camera? Or what would be the best way to approach this?

I'm on a MacBook M1 Pro with Monterey 12.3.1

Answer (score 2):

Run the same code from the command line. It will ask for camera permission and let you use your app on second run.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command

```
tccutil reset Camera
```

in the same terminal from where you're running the code. Mac will ask for authorisation. Then kill the python process and restart. It should then work!